# AssetBundles with shaders that contain #include to cg/hlsl

Tags: unity

I have a shader that contains some #includes to other cg/hlsl scripts. If i put that shader into an AssetBundle, how am i suppose to handle the cg/hlsl scripts?

Are they not necessary anymore because they are compiled into the shader during the AssetBundle build process? Unity version is 5.6.6f2

Or do i have to put the cg/hlsl scripts into the AssetBundle too? If that is the case, how do I load them during runtime such that the Shader finds them?

Someone suggested me to inline them, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every shader ends up self-contained, actually (besides the fallback directives). The include directive is processed by the compiler and goes away in the compiled shader, whether it’s in an AssetBundle or not.

Comment: good to know, thx!